# Почему выводится ошибка index out of range

Tags: python, массивы, list, матрицы

```
n = int(input())
b=1
a=[[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
for i in range(n+1):
    for j in range(n+1):
        if [0][0]<=[i][j]<=[0][n]:
            a[i][j]+=b
            b+=1
print(a)
```

Comment: покажите ошибку

Comment: массивы ты формируешь до range(n), а в цикле пробегаешь до range(n+1), соответственно иногда твой цикл будет проверять элемент с ошибочным индексом

Comment: заменил range(n-1) на range(n), ошибка осталась

Comment: @PuhoviyLw А во всех циклах заменили? И скиньте уже вывод ошибки. Там же конкретное место указано, где возникает ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Вот эти строки

```
for i in range(n+1):
    for j in range(n+1):
        if [0][0]<=[i][j]<=[0][n]:
```

необходимо заменить на эти:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if a[0][0] <= a[i][j] <= a[0][n-1]:
```

Полный правильный код такой:

```
n = int(input())
b = 1
a = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if a[0][0] <= a[i][j] <= a[0][n - 1]:
            a[i][j] += b
            b += 1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

При формировании матрицы

```py
a=[[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
```

вы определяете массив индексов как `range(n)`, что при `n = 3` вернет список `[0, 1, 2]`. А в условии:

```py
if [0][0]<=[i][j]<=[0][n]:
```

последняя группа индексов определена от самого значения `n`, то есть `[0][3]`. Именно здесь и возникает ошибка. Вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу, которого не существует.

Да и в целом синтаксис с группами индексов не понятен. Вы их берете откуда-то из воздуха. Нужно указать саму матрицу:

```py
if a[0][0] <= a[i][j] <= a[0][n]:
```

В итоге правильный код будет таким:

```py
n = int(input())
b=1
a=[[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if a[0][0] <= a[i][j] <= a[0][n-1]:
            a[i][j]+=b
            b+=1
print(a)
```

Comment: А что за синтаксис `[0][0]`?

Comment: Вроде как это 0 всегда возвращает `¯\_[0]__[0]_/¯`

Comment: @dIm0n если честно - я тоже не понял. Но вопрос то про ошибку.А она возбуждается именно на последней группе индексов